# Html page redirection in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one html page and in that page i have 3 buttons.
Each button should redirect to a seperate html page.
Can u please look into the below code and guide me where am wrong.

```
<td class="span3 offset6 alignment">
  <%= submit_tag 'Add To Cart', products_path %>
</td>
<td class="span3 offset9 alignment">
  <%= submit_tag 'Check Out', orders_path %>
</td>
<td class="span3 offset12 alignment">
  <%= submit_tag 'View Cart', viewcart_path %>
</td>
```

Comment: Why would you use submit_tag for these buttons? Wouldn't just normal links suffice?

Comment: Can you please tell what exactly the problem is along with some code ?

Answer (score 3):

`submit_tag` is used inside a `form`.

Is this case it looks like you want to use
`<%= link_to 'View Cart', viewcart_path %>`

Answer (score 0):

`submit_tag` would not have path, as its in form. Path would be specified in form action attribute. You need to require `link_to` for your purpose. Please go through this documentation for [submit_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag) and [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
<%= button_to "Add To Cart", products_path, :method => "get" %>
```